# How to quit second display

Tags: 22.04

Why do I have these two displays, and how do I quit one?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

That is workspaces, not displays. Workspaces offers a way to organize your program windows more virtual screens.

Right-click on disktop choose **Display Settings** and then **Multitasking** to configure Workspaces.

The default setting is **Dynamic workspaces** where the system will make a new workspace ready when the last one is used - so you will have at least two workspaces.

Alternatively you can choose **Fixed number of workspacess** to have a fixed number, one or more.